# i have to show a new field count.that is the count of each requirement id in jil_mrorfq table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i have a manage page with pagination with field like Requirement Service,Posted By,Managed By,Quantity,Posted On,Status from the table requirement. i have to show a new filed count.that is the count of each requirement id in jil_mrorfq table.
i done the portion of manage.but i dont konw how show the count,how it fetch together with this code.Anyone know the query,please help me to do this task.
i  correctly done the manage page with pagination.but the count of each requirement id have to show as next field in the table.i am totally confused how it fetch.how the query will write.anybody knows the answer,then please help me to complete this task.

MY Controller

```
public function managerequirement() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "moderator/Requirement/managerequirement";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->requirement_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'first';
        $config['last_link'] = 'last';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) :0;
        $data["results"]= $this->requirement_model->
                fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page); 
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('moderator/managerequirement', $data);
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');
    }
```

MY Model

```
 public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
         $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
          $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
           $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
           $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
        $query =  $this->db->get();  
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                 $data[] = $row;
            }
           return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

View

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">

                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <th class="sorting" width="5%">#</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="30%">Requirement Service</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="10%">Posted By</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="10%">Managed By</th>
                                         <th class="sorting" width="15%">Quantity</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="15%">Posted  On</th>

                                        <th class="sorting" width="15%">Status</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <?php
                                     if(!empty($results))
                                    {
                                    foreach ($results as $row) {
                                        ?><tr>  
                                            <td class=" "><?php echo $row->rqm_id; ?></td>  
                                            <td class=" ">   <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'moderator/Requirement/viewrequirementdetails/' . $row->rqm_id ?>"><?php echo $row->rqm_service; ?></a></td>
                                           <td class=" "><?php
                                           echo $row->usr_name;

                                           ?></td>  
                                           <td class=" "><?php
                                           echo $row->mer_name;

                                           ?></td>  
                                             <td class=" "><?php
                                           echo $row->rqm_quantity;

                                           ?></td>  
                                             <td class=" "><?php echo date('d-M-Y',$row->rqm_dated);?></td>  
                                             <td class=" "><?php 
                                             if($row->rqm_permission=='0')
                                             {
                                                 echo "In-Active";

                                             }
                                            else if($row->rqm_permission=='1')
                                             {
                                                 echo "Active";

                                             }
                                               else if($row->rqm_permission=='2')
                                             {
                                                 echo "Pending";

                                             }
                                               else if($row->rqm_permission=='3')
                                             {
                                                 echo "Suspend";

                                             }
                                               else if($row->rqm_permission=='4')
                                             {
                                                 echo "Delete";

                                             }
                                             ?></td>  

                                        </tr>  
                                    <?php }
                                    }
                                    ?>  

                                </table>

                                <?php echo $links; ?>   
                            </div>
```

Comment: where you use the jil_mrorfq table in your coding ?

Comment: i already specified in the question i have to do that task. have to find each reqid count from jil_mrorfq table.can u help?

Comment: pls share your jil_mrorfq  table reqid count query with code

Comment: $this->db->select('count(jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid) as reqcount'); 
$this->db->from('jil_mrorfq'); 
$this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left'); 
$this->db->group_by('jil_requirements.rqm_id'); 
$query2= $this->db->get();

Comment: i want a single query to complte all task. in my model i wrote a query to manage,i need count result along with that code

Comment: @Angel Can you clear question. I cant get any idea about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
  public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
      $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
      $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
      $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
      $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
      $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
      $query =  $this->db->get();  
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
          $this->db->select('count(jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid) as total'); 
          $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq'); 
          $this->db->where('jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid',$row->rqm_id);
          $this->db->group_by('jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid'); 
          $query2= $this->db->get()->row_object();

         $row->total_count = $query2->total;
         $data[] = $row;
                }
               return $data;
            }
            return false;
       }
```

Comment: hiii vinie using this code can we get the whole data as well as the count of each requirement id?

Comment: i tried your code.but i getting a single number all the time.

Comment: vinie i have to find the count of each requirement id in the jil_requirement table

Comment: requirement id belongs to which table

Comment: vinie i have to fetch one thing too.can u help?

Comment: vinie that is another problem. i give new question in stackoverflow.thats is a sidebar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053362/sidebar-sliding-issue-when-a-ajax-function-calls-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding

```
  public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
             $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
              $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
               $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
            $query =  $this->db->get();  
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $key=>$row) {
                     $data[$key] = $row;

$this->db->select('jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid'); 
$this->db->from('jil_mrorfq'); 
$this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left');
 $this->db->group_by('jil_requirements.rqm_id'); 
$query2= $this->db->get();

 $data[$key]['count'] =$query2->num_rows();
                }
               return $data;
            }
            return false;
       }
```

Comment: Glad help to you, can you accept answer and upvote ?