# Sidebar sliding issue when a ajax function calls in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have an add function in codeigniter controller thats work using ajax. when click on Add Rfq in sidebar .and again trying to click on any other link on the sidebar it automatically closing.why affecting this function in sidebar working?

[image][![sidebar view]
Controller Function

```
public function addrfqoffline() {
        $content = "";
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $data['customers'] = $this->userdata_model->usersname();
        $data['merchants'] = $this->merchant_model->merchantname();
        // $data['mroproducts']=$this->mroproduct_model->mroproductname();
        $data['units'] = $this->requirement_model->fetchunits();
        if ($this->input->post("from") != "ajax") {
            $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header', '', true);
            $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar', '', true);
            $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfq', $data, true);

            $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer', '', true);
        } else {
            $rid = $this->input->post('reqid');
            $requirement = $this->requirement_model->viewdata($rid);
            if ($requirement) {
                foreach ($requirement as $reqdata) {
                    $dat['reqid'] = $reqdata->rqm_id;
                    $dat['service'] = $reqdata->rqm_service;
                    $dat['quantity'] = $reqdata->rqm_quantity;
                    $dat['service'] = $reqdata->rqm_service;
                    $dat['details'] = $reqdata->rqm_requirements;
                    $dat['unitrqm'] = $reqdata->rqm_unit;
                     $dat['userid'] = $reqdata->rqm_userid;
                    $unitname = $this->requirement_model->unitname($reqdata->rqm_unit);
                    foreach ($unitname as $unitsingle) {
                        $dat['unitname'] = $unitsingle->name;
                    }
                    $usernames= $this->requirement_model->username($reqdata->rqm_userid);
                    foreach($usernames as $username)
                    {

                        $dat['username']=$username->usr_name;
                         $dat['usercompany']=$username->usr_company;


                    }
                    if ($this->input->post("from") == "ajax") {
                        $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfq', array_merge($dat, $data), true);
                    }
                }
            } else if (!$requirement) {

                $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfq', $data, true);
            }
        }

        echo $content; // this will echo the view here
    }
```

Sidebar code

```
 <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Request for Quotation </span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu"> 

                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addrfqoffline"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>New Offline RFQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/managerfq"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>Manage RFQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    function getValue(val) {
        //alert(val);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addrfqoffline",
            data: {from: "ajax", reqid: val},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#rfqsubmit').click(function () {

 var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/addoffline",
            type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           dataType:"Json", 
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+last_inserted_id;
                // window.location.href ="<?php //echo base_url()             ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+  form_data.reqid;
//      alert('added Successfully');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



</script>
```

Comment: what are you asking? I didn't understand.

Comment: hi vinie. when i click on the add offline rfq in sidebar,that page wil appear.again i click on any other option in sidebar that wil speedly closes the listing

Comment: which listing closes?

Comment: still not understanding

Comment: please show your ajax request code

Comment: did you see the sidebar.when whe click on a option 2 listing wil come 1)add 2)manage. when i click on add rfqoffline. that add form wil appear.again i click any option on sidebar. that listing is not lists constantly.it closes soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101860/discussion-between-angel-and-vinie).

Comment: vinie,are you there? if you dont mind can u come on chat or give ur email id

Comment: i am on chat please come there.